# Using string.replace() to replace difference variations of the same word

Tags: javascript

Im looking to replace "hate" with "love". I am having a hard time figuring out how to replace different variations of "hate" ie. "haaate" or "hattteeee" with "love". Any advice would be awesome. Thanks

```
var tape = " I hate work. I haaaate fire. I  haaatttee school";

var pope = tape.replace(/hate/gi,function ool (x){
return  x.replace(/hate/gi,"love")
})

console.log(pope) ===> I love work. I **haaaate** fire. I  haaatttee school
```

Comment: String.replace accepts regex: `s.replace(/h+a+t+e+/gi, 'love'):` You might want to look for phonetical or other similarity though to cover more cases

Comment: Good point. I noticed that if :   hate was turned to Shate it would still replace only the hate part and leave the rest. How do I exclude Shate  when using this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a regex to match each letter multiple times e.g. `/\bh+a+t+e+\b/`, note that `\b` stands for word boundary which means that only words that start with `h` and end with `e` will be changed

```js
var tape = " I hate work. I haaaate fire. I  haaatttee school, shate and hates should not change";
var pope = tape.replace(/\bh+a+t+e+\b/gi, 'love')
console.log(pope)
```

Comment: You could expand it to match similar characters, like haaattt3, by doing something like \bh+[a@]+[t+]+[e3]+\b

Answer (score 0):

If you can't express all the variations using complex regular expressions and you are only looking for a small number of variations, you could use the `| (or operator)` in the regular expressions, as shown below:

```js
var tape = " I hate work. I haaaate fire. I  haaatttee school";

var pope = tape.replace(/hate|haaaate|haaatttee/gi,"love");

console.log(pope);
```